# Prove $|f'(x)|\leq 2\sqrt{ab}.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

## Problem

Assume that for all $x \in (0, +\infty)$, $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ exist, and $|f(x)|\leq a, |f''(x)|\leq b$. Prove that $|f'(x)|\leq 2\sqrt{ab}.$

## My Proof

For any $x,h>0$，according to Taylor's formula expanding at $x$，we have$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}h^2,$$
where $0<x<\xi<x+h.$
Thus
\begin{align*}
|f'(x)h|&=|f(x+h)-f(x)-\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}h^2|\\
&\leq |f(x+h)|+|f(x)|+\frac{|f''(\xi)|}{2}h^2\\
&\leq a+a+\frac{bh^2}{2}\\
&=2a+\frac{bh^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
This shows the inequality
$$|f'(x)|\leq \frac{2a}{h}+\frac{bh}{2}$$
holds for all $h>0$. Denote
$$g(h):=\frac{2a}{h}+\frac{bh}{2},\forall h>0.$$
Then $|f'(x)|$ can not exceed the minimum value of $g(h)$. Since
$$g(h)=\frac{2a}{h}+\frac{bh}{2}\geq 2\sqrt{\frac{2a}{h} \cdot \frac{bh}{2}}=2\sqrt{ab},$$
hence
$$|f'(x)|\leq 2\sqrt{ab}.$$
The proof is completed.

**Please rectify it if it's wrong. Hope to see other proof.**

Comment: The use of Taylor series assumes all high order derivatives exist

Comment: No, it's twice differentiable. We only need that to solve the present problem.

Comment: in line 5, when you write "$<=$" , you must have assumed that $f(x)$ and its second derivative are positive. Maybe not so.

Answer (score 2):

It should be a comment, but due to its worthiness, I make it a post. Since $|f'(x)| \le \dfrac{2a}{h}+ \dfrac{bh}{2}, \forall h > 0$, take $h = 2\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}$, and this gives $|f'(x)| \le 2\sqrt{ab}$

Comment: @mengdie1982. It is also useful to note that the value $$h=2\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$ is the only positive solution of the equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}g(h)=o,$$ i.e. *it minimizes $g(h)$ over all positive $h$*.